# Folder permissions control

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, file-permissions

Scenario :

i work in a company with 50+ computers in a domain.

One of the PC has a trouble with My Document is missing.

So i was thinking of creating a new Folder call My Documents , then i get an error that says the folder exists.

i was shocked to see that , so i tried the "dir /ah" and it really did show
my documents on the tree.

i did attrib to that folder. and finally the folder shows it self

But it shows itself with the small shortcut icon and accessing it gives me permission denied.

i tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows method.

still no avail.

All users now have Full permission yet i am still not able to open the folder.

I tried multiple recovery tools and recovery method to no avail.

Can i have an assist? I want to access that folder as it contains the user's 1 year work flow.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is actually a symbolic link/junction(I'm not sure of the exact term). It's there to provide compatibility to programs meant for older operating systems (Windows XP and older line-ups).

[image]

It isn't the 'My Documents' folder that you were actually searching for. It might either have been deleted, or moved to a different location. In this case, you can just type `documents` in the address bar and see where that link leads to, if it's still there.

You can try file recovery programs instead. Although, by now most of the allocated space for those deleted files may have been overwritten, in case the documents folder used to reside in the system drive. Never the less, it's still worth a try, to retrieve whatever possible.

I would suggest Active@ File recovery(although not a freeware) as it maintains the folder structure on the file-system, which might be ideal for retrieving large folder structures.

Comment: Nooooooooo~~~~ im seeing exactly like what you've given...

i tried recuva , FTK , PhotoRec , norton recovery..

Comment: Yes ... i do agree... i think so , that the folder might be deleted as well..

as he lost about 200gb files , now back to 400gb free storage..

Comment: Have you tried typing 'documents' in the address bar?

Comment: Most file recovery programs only allow you to search by file-names. I would highly recommend using a program that shows the filesystem as is, alongside deleted folders/files for navigation, so that one can navigate to the folder. Deleted items should show up alongside existing ones. It should be possible to see those files(atleast some of them) unless someone has deliberately cleaned up the file system thoroughly to prevent recovery.

Comment: yes i've tried the documents in the address bar.. :(

Comment: Restore from backup. You do **have** backups, right?

Comment: @DavidPostill - unfortunately....... that user did not do backups of his work....